# How to pass a value from codebehind to .js in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i need to pass a value from page load to .js file .

can anyone please help?

Comment: What u tried please explain ur question in details also add some code so we can understand batter ..

Answer (score 3):

You can declare an HTML hidden control..

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden"  runat="server" clientidmode="Static" value="0"/>
```

Set value from code behind..

```
Hidden1.value="Something";
```

Access in your javascript function...

```
function abc()
{
   document.getElementId('Hidden1').value;
}
```

Comment: Please feel free to mark as answer if it satisfies you,Regards..

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** directly pass value from code behind to js file although you can pass to .aspx (html), you can then call .js file function to pass value to it. You need public property/attribute in code behind for that.

*In code behind*

```
public stirng YourPublicProperty  { get; set; }
```

*In javascript*

```
var inJs = '<%= YourPublicProperty %>';
someFunctionInJs(inJs);
```

*Or*

```
someFunctionInJs('<%= YourPublicProperty %>');
```

*In .js file*

```
function someFunctionInJs(para)
{
   alert(para);
}
```

Comment: This won't work if `YourPublicProperty` is updated on the code-behind and needs to also be updated on the frontend. The reason is that the `.js` file only loads once (on page load) and the value of `YourPublicProperty` is "hardcoded" then. So in such a case, the `.js` file needs to be reloaded.